# Alternative to Vlookup in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

A strange question perhaps, but is there an alternative way of opening a workbook, searching for a particular reference in a column, and then pulling the data from a another column in that row using VBA, without using VLookup?

The table I am trying to get data from contains a mixture of numbers, text, dates, and the lookup value is often >13 digits long.

I sort of had something working with VLookup, but it was too inconsistent - every so often it would just break because the data type didn't match. An awful lot of 'type mismatch' or 'ByRef' errors - I'd get one right and then another breaks.

Unfortunately I don't know enough to know what to search to get me in the right direction.

If it helps explain what I'm trying to do, here's my code using VLookup that errors all the time:

```
Sub getData()

Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.Calculation = xlManual

Dim wb As Workbook, src As Workbook
Dim srcRange As Range
Dim InputString
Dim strStatus
Dim strStatusNum
Dim strD1
Dim I As Integer

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

I = 7

Set src = Workbooks.Open("D:\Files\test2.xlsx", True, True)
    With src.Sheets(1)
        Set srcRange = .Range(.Range("A1"), .Range("H1").End(xlDown))
End With

Do While wb.ActiveSheet.Cells(I, 1) <> ""

    'Makes sure src.Close is called if errors
    'On Error Resume Next

    InputString = wb.Worksheets("Sheet 1").Cells(I, 1)

    strStatus = Application.VLookup(InputString, srcRange, 3, False)

    strD1 = Application.VLookup(InputString, srcRange, 4, False)

    'Convert strStatus to actual number e.g. "03. no d1"
    strStatusNum = Left(strStatus, 2)

    wb.Worksheets("Sheet 1").Cells(I, 4) = strStatusNum

        If (strStatusNum <> 3) Then

            wb.Worksheets("Sheet 1").Cells(I, 2) = "Not at 03. No Work Order"

        ElseIf (strStatusNum = 3) And (strD1 <> "") Then

            wb.Worksheets("Sheet 1").Cells(I, 2) = "D1 Received"
            wb.Worksheets("Sheet 1").Cells(I, 3) = strD1

        Else

            wb.Worksheets("Sheet 1").Cells(I, 2) = "No D1"

        End If

    I = I + 1

Loop


src.Close (False)

Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic

End Sub
```

EDIT: Corrected some syntax.

Comment: Before trying to use `strStatus` or `strD1` you should test them using `IsError()` - that will tell you whether the lookup failed (so returning an error value).  If there's no error then continue with the rest of the logic.  Also - you have `strD142` in your code but there's no variable declared. If you don't have `Option Explicit` at the top of every module then that should be first on your to-do list.

Comment: I was stepping through the code and it was always error 2042. In the end, I felt that using VLookup for what I was trying to do was just not really feasible. The data type varies too much, even using `Variant` didn't seem to work consistently.

The strD142 was an error I added when trying to generalise the code above, as it refers to some industry codes. You'll have to excuse the poor notation for that reason!

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [`Find`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find) method of the [`Range`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range(object)) object, in your case of the column. The return value is the first cell (represented as another `Range` object) with a matching value, unless there is no match at all. Then `Nothing` is returned.

On the returned (single cell) range you can use the [`EntireRow`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.entirerow) method to get a Range that represents all the cells on the row of the found cell. On the returned (row) range you can use the [`Cells`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.cells) method to select the cell matching the column in the same row, that you want to return (again represented as another `Range` object).

By the way, a more flexible alternative to [`VLOOKUP`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.vlookup) in workbook functions is a combination of [`INDEX`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.index) and [`MATCH`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.match).

Comment: Thank you for that. Can you further explain how I count along _x_ number of columns from my returned range and get that value?

So lets imagine I do `strStatus = .Find(InputString)` and that finds the value in cell A10 - how do I then get to cell H10 and get that data?

Comment: @WillC To get to column `H` in the row where you found the match in cell `rngStatus` you can use `rngStatus.EntireRow.Cells(1,8)`. BTW, your Hungarian notation supposes that the result of the search is a String. However, it is a range.

Comment: RE: the notation - this is a legacy of trying to use a vlookup on a range of data types..Going to tidying it up once I've got the code working.

Unfortunately I can't seem to get anything to work. I'm just not understanding the syntax I guess.

`With srcRange
InputString = wb.Worksheets("UsefulTools").Cells(i, 1)
Set rngStatus = srcRange.Find(InputString)
strStatus = rngStatus.EntireRow.Cells(1, 8)
wb.Worksheets("UsefulTools").Cells(i, 2) = strStatus
I = I + 1
End With
Loop`

Not sure what's not working that that.

Comment: Your code in the comment is very hard to understand with the missing line breaks. Moreover, it would help a lot if you did not use the default property of the ranges and called `Value` explicitly wherever you want to use the value in the cell. Furthermore, you do not seem to consider the case that no match is found, i.e. you do not test for `rngStatus Is Nothing`. If you do not do this, you will get an error whenever the input string is not found because you cannot call methods on `Nothing`.

Comment: I'm not accounting for Nothing because I know what my test range contains so I find it helps to troubleshoot other issues beforehand. I appreciate that code is hard to understand. I might just stick with my dodgy vlookups, this seems needlessly complicated. You'd think this sort of look up would simple in VBA: Find x in this column, get y from same row in column z.

Answer (score 0):

Untested but compiled:

```
Sub getData()

    Dim src As Workbook
    Dim srcRange As Range
    Dim strStatus, strStatusNum, strD1
    Dim m, rw As Range

    Set rw = ActiveSheet.Rows(7)

    Set src = Workbooks.Open("D:\Files\test2.xlsx", True, True)
    With src.Sheets(1)
        Set srcRange = .Range(.Range("A1"), .Range("H1").End(xlDown))
    End With

    Do While rw.Cells(1).Value <> ""

        m = Application.Match(rw.Cells(1), srcRange.Columns(1), 0)

        If Not IsError(m) Then 'proceed only if got match

            strStatus = srcRange.Cells(m, 3).Value
            strD1 = srcRange.Cells(m, 4).Value
            strStatusNum = Left(strStatus, 2)

            rw.Cells(4).Value = strStatusNum

            If strStatusNum <> 3 Then
                rw.Cells(2) = "Not at 03. No Work Order"
            ElseIf strStatusNum = 3 And strD1 <> "" Then
                rw.Cells(2) = "D1 Received"
                rw.Cells(3) = strD1
            Else
                rw.Cells(2) = "No D1"
            End If

        End If

        Set rw = rw.Offset(1, 0)

    Loop

    src.Close False

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. I have tried this but it doesn't seem to find anything. If I take out the error handling, strStatus gets error 2042 (I.e. nothing found), even though I know for a fact 'm' exists in the two workbooks.

Comment: In that case it would help to share some sample data for testing

Answer (score 0):

you may be after this refactoring of your code

```
Sub getData() 
    Dim wbRng As Range, cell As Range, f As Range
    Dim strStatus, strStatusNum, strD1 

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.Calculation = xlManual


    With ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
        Set wbRng = .Range("A7:A" & WorksheetFunction.Max(7, .Cells(.Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)) '<--| set the range of values to be searched for
        If WorksheetFunction.CountA(wbRng) = 0 Then Exit Sub '<--| exit if no values under row 7
        Set wbRng = wbRng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)  '<--| narrow the range of values to be searched for down to not blank values only
    End With

    With Workbooks.Open("D:\Files\test2.xlsx", True, True).Sheets(1) '<--| open wanted workbook and reference its first sheet
        With .Range("A1:A" & .Cells(.Rows.count, "H").End(xlUp).Row) '<--| reference its column A range from row 1 down to column H last not empty cell (this is your former "srcRange")
            For Each cell In wbRng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants) '<--| loop through range of values to be searched for
                Set f = .Find(what:=cell.Value, lookat:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues) '<--| look referenced range for current value to be searched for
                If Not f Is Nothing Then '<--| if found
                    strStatus = f.Offset(, 2).Value
                    strD1 = f.Offset(, 3).Value

                    'Convert strStatus to actual number e.g. "03. no d1"
                    strStatusNum = val(Left(strStatus, 2)) '<--| use 'Val()' function to convert string "03" to "3"
                    cell.Offset(, 3) = strStatusNum
                    Select Case True
                        Case strStatusNum <> 3
                            cell.Offset(, 1).Value = "Not at 03. No Work Order"
                        Case strStatusNum = 3 And (strD1 <> "")
                            cell.Offset(, 1).Resize(, 2).Value = Array("D1 Received", strD1)
                        Case Else
                            cell.Offset(, 1).Value = "No D1"
                    End Select
                End If
            Next
        End With
        .Parent.Close False
    End With

    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic

End Sub
```